# How to add "load more" view at bottom of StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` with `spanCount = 2` with `VERTICAL` orientation. It is an endless list. How to add *load more animation* on pagination?

The problem with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` is that I am not able to provide dynamic `spanCount` at row level. If it was `GridLayoutManager` this was simple with `SpanSizeLookup`. If you have any solution or suggestion please throw away. Thanks!

Pinterest has already added... But is their own custom or native I have no idea
[image]

Comment: at the bottom of the recyclerview?

Comment: certainly at the bottom.. whole layout is with 2 columns... but load more animation should have only 1 column

Comment: Its not like we should add load more to the recyclerview it self. We can try this in the layout file itself which contains the recyclerview. And need to implement some logic to do that.

Comment: no I am already using it... as separate view when I am using 1 column. it is damn easy thing, but with staggered with more than 1 column, load more animation comes under last element instead of next row. This is what I am trying to crack. May be I must try to portray my problem with other image which will make it comparable to the pinterest image

Comment: Check out the solution I have mentioned below. Forgot to post it over here, but I think it will be useful for many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some R&D, I got solution to be working on spans on StaggeredGridView. So it would be either number of columns specified or full span.

What needs to be done is add below code in adapter for each view in `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
                    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This is perfect working solution for me as of now without specifying any column span count.